# How to get each column from this text by awk?

Tags: awk

Contents in the text file:

```
abc [abc d] "abcd e" test
abc [abc d] "-" test
```

Basically each column is separated by a whitespace. But there are also some whitespaces in the contents in some columns and in this case the whole contents would be wrapped with [] or "" as in the examples above. How can I get the correct column by awk?

The correct column should be

1: abc 2: [abc d] 3: "abcd e" 4: test

1: abc 2: [abc d] 3: "-" 4: test

But not:

1: abc 2: [abc 3: d] 4: "abcd 5: e" 4: test

Comment: if you have GNU awk, search for FPAT... add sample expected output for operations you need and also what you have tried to solve this

Comment: What would the columns be if the input was `abc "foo[bar" def "oh]no"` or `abc [foo "bar]" def"]` or similar? Basically -  if square brackets can occur within double quotes or vice-versa then include those in your sample input /output and explain how to resolve the conflict. Also include escaped double quotes inside the quoted fields if that can occur, e.g. `abc "foo "" bar" def` or `abc "foo \" bar" def`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU awk you could use [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^ ]+)|([[][^][]+[]])|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
{
    print $3
}' file
"abcd e"
"-"
```

This example considers as a field:

- strings separated by spaces `[^ ]+`
- strings enclosed in square brackets `[[][^][]+[]]`
- strings enclosed in double quotes `"[^\"]+\"`

I didn't test what happens if enclosed in something is enclosed in something else. If you do, please report back.

Comment: The middle string should really be `[^][]`, not `[^]]` since you're assuming that neither `[` nor `]` will occur within `[...]`. I suspect this approach might fail if `[` can appear in a quoted string though, e.g. `"foo[bar"`, and vice-versa. idk if that can occur or not of course.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you. After 7 weeks of vacation I got so lost in those brackets  that it was like my first day with Lisp.